# How to capture result of sub-processes within shell

Tags: linux, subprocess

Here is the problem I have: I want to trigger n different subprocesses (functions calling dql procedures) in parallel within my script and I want to capture the result (not the return code) of each function call within a separate variable. e.g. if the function run_oracle returns the square of the number passed to it then I need something on these lines

```
X=`run_oracle 1 &`
Y=`run_oracle 2 &`
Z=`run_oracle 3 &`
```

The resultant values within X, Y and Z variables should be 1, 4 and 9. Is there a way to do this without writing the results to intermediate files or tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html

read the part on Example 20-3. Running parallel processes in subshells

also don't forget the "wait" command